# Amazon S3 Transfer Manager v2.x and metadata

Tags: java, amazon-s3, spring-webflux

I would like to use the new version (2.x) of Amazon S3 Transfer Manager to upload a directory to a bucket. I can do it without problems except for metadata.
I need to set some metadata (content-type and content-encoding) for each file.
I can do it with the version 1.x (below an example) but not with the new version

```
MultipleFileUpload upload = tm.uploadDirectory(
                                bucket,
                                prefix,
                                filePath.toFile(),
                                true,
                                (file, metadata) -> {
                          
                                    String mimeType = "application/json";
                                    try {
                                        mimeType = Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(file.toURI()));

                                        if (mimeType == null) {
                                            if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains("bulkdata")) {
                                                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                                            }
                                            if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".raw")) {
                                                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                                            }
                                            if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains("frames")) {
                                                mimeType = "multipart/related";
                                            }
                                            if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains("thumbnail")) {
                                                mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                                    }

                                    if (file.getName().endsWith(".gz")) {
                                        metadata.setContentEncoding("gzip");
                                        mimeType = "application/json";
                                    }

                                    metadata.setContentType(mimeType);
                                }
                        );
```

Do you know a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Maybe https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/model/UploadDirectoryRequest.Builder.html#uploadFileRequestTransformer(java.util.function.Consumer) !?

Comment: Thank you @luk2302 for your suggestion, I will try and I let you know asap

Comment: @luk2302 I tried your solution and I think that this is the right way BUT I don't know how can I retrieve the file is going to be uploaded inside the transformer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

As suggested by @luk2302 the way is to implement the `uploadFileRequestTransformer`.

```
UploadDirectoryRequest request = UploadDirectoryRequest.builder()
    .bucket(bucket)
    .s3Prefix(prefix)
    .source(filePath)
    .uploadFileRequestTransformer(uploadFileRequestBuilder -> {
         UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest = uploadFileRequestBuilder.build();

         File file = uploadFileRequest.source().toFile();
                    
         String mimeType = "application/json";
         try {
             mimeType = Files.probeContentType(uploadFileRequest.source());

             if (mimeType == null) {
                 if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains("bulkdata")) {
                     mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                 }
                 if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".raw")) {
                     mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                 }
                 if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains("frames")) {
                     mimeType = "multipart/related";
                 }
                 if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains("thumbnail")) {
                     mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                 }
             }
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
         }

         PutObjectRequest.Builder putObjectRequestBuilder = uploadFileRequest.putObjectRequest().toBuilder();
         if (file.getName().endsWith(".gz")) {
             putObjectRequestBuilder.contentEncoding("gzip");

             mimeType = "application/json";
         }

         putObjectRequestBuilder.contentType(mimeType);

         uploadFileRequestBuilder.putObjectRequest(putObjectRequestBuilder.build());
    }).build();
```